# Lucene.net: How to control order of operations with multiple terms

Tags: lucene.net

Is it possible to control the order of operations when using multiple terms?

For example,

```
Lucene.Net.Search.TermQuery tq1 = new Lucene.Net.Search.TermQuery(new Lucene.Net.Index.Term("location", "seattle"));
Lucene.Net.Search.TermQuery tq2 = new Lucene.Net.Search.TermQuery(new Lucene.Net.Index.Term("location", "portland"));
Lucene.Net.Search.TermQuery tq3 = new Lucene.Net.Search.TermQuery(new Lucene.Net.Index.Term("location", "spokane"));
Lucene.Net.Search.TermQuery tq4 = new Lucene.Net.Search.TermQuery(new Lucene.Net.Index.Term("type", "city"));
```

When I apply a search, lets say I want to apply the above Terms to filter my search, lets search for food...so my query format would look something like below

food AND ((tq1 OR tq2 OR tq3) AND tq4)

Currently I've been able to build it in the following format

```
{+xml:food +(location:seattle location:portland location:spokane +location:city)}
```

But, I am trying to get it in the format of

```
{+xml:food +(+(location:seattle location:portland location:spokane) +location:city)}
```

Basically, what I do is something like this...

```
Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanQuery bq = new Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanQuery();
Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanQuery innerBQ = new Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanQuery();
bq.Add("xml:food", Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
foreach (Lucene.Net.Index.Term term in listOfTerms)
{
    Lucene.Net.Search.TermQuery tq = new Lucene.Net.Search.TermQuery(term));
    innerBQ.Add(tq, Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
}
innerBQ.Add("location:city", Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
bq.Add(innerBQ, Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your `location:city` clause to `bq` instead of `innerBQ`

Comment: Thanks.  Just had to stare at it a little bit more and understand how these Boolean queries get assembled..